# Error creating bean with the name. unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I know there is a lot of questions and answers about this problem, but It seems for everyone is a different situation and after one hour of searching for a solution I didnt find out how to fix this, so I hope someone can give me some directions or can see what I'm missing, thanks in advance, I'll provide as much as useful code from my implementations, but if I need to provide something more I'm here.

The full error stack trace is:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'appUserService' defined in file [D:\portfolio\TripAdvisorApp\target\classes\demo\tripadvisorapp\security\appuser\AppUserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appUserRepository' defined in demo.tripadvisorapp.security.appuser.AppUserRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract int demo.tripadvisorapp.security.appuser.AppUserRepository.enableAppUser(java.lang.String); Reason: No property 'enableAppUser' found for type 'AppUser'; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'enableAppUser' found for type 'AppUser'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at demo.tripadvisorapp.TripAdvisorAppApplication.main(TripAdvisorAppApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appUserRepository' defined in demo.tripadvisorapp.security.appuser.AppUserRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract int demo.tripadvisorapp.security.appuser.AppUserRepository.enableAppUser(java.lang.String); Reason: No property 'enableAppUser' found for type 'AppUser'; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'enableAppUser' found for type 'AppUser'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract int demo.tripadvisorapp.security.appuser.AppUserRepository.enableAppUser(java.lang.String); Reason: No property 'enableAppUser' found for type 'AppUser'; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'enableAppUser' found for type 'AppUser'
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:107) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1054) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:87) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:87) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:365) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:231) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:119) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'enableAppUser' found for type 'AppUser'
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:91) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:438) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:414) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:367) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:349) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:332) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:384) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:385) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:93) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.PartTreeMongoQuery.<init>(PartTreeMongoQuery.java:67) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory$MongoQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:215) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.1.jar:3.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:103) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
```

Now I'm providing part by part of code from stack trace:

`AppUserService`:

```
    @Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AppUserService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final static String USER_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE = "User with email %s not found";
    private final AppUserRepository appUserRepository;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    private final ConfirmationTokenService confirmationTokenService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return appUserRepository.findByEmail(email).orElseThrow(() ->
                new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format(USER_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE, email)));
    }

    public String signUpUser(AppUser appUser) {
        boolean userExists = appUserRepository.findByEmail(appUser.getEmail())
                .isPresent();
        if (userExists) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Email already taken");
        }
        String encodedPassword = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(appUser.getPassword());

        appUser.setPassword(encodedPassword);

        appUserRepository.save(appUser);

        String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        ConfirmationToken confirmationToken = new ConfirmationToken(
                token,
                LocalDateTime.now(),
                LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(15),
                appUser
        );

        confirmationTokenService.saveConfirmationToken(confirmationToken);

        return token;
    }

    public int enableAppUser(String email) {
        return appUserRepository.enableAppUser(email);
    }

}
```

`AppUserRepository`

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Repository
public interface AppUserRepository extends MongoRepository<AppUser, Long> {

    Optional<AppUser> findByEmail(String email);

    @Transactional
    int enableAppUser(String email);

}
```

`AppUser`:

```
    @Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document("app_user")
public class AppUser implements UserDetails {

        @Id
        private String id;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String email;
        private String password;
        private AppUserRole appUserRole;
        private Boolean locked = false;
        private Boolean enabled = false;
    
        public AppUser(String firstName,
                       String lastName,
                       String email,
                       String password,
                       AppUserRole appUserRole) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.email = email;
            this.password = password;
            this.appUserRole = appUserRole;
        }
    
        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(appUserRole.name());
            return Collections.singletonList(authority);
        }
    
        @Override
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String getUsername() {
            return email;
        }
    
        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }
    
        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
            return !locked;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return enabled;
        }
    }
```

I tried to add

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"demo.tripadvisorapp.security.token"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"demo.tripadvisorapp.security.appuser"})
```

But that doesnt fixed it.

EDIT:

From suggested answer I created a Custom Repository and now I'm getting this error:

```
    Parameter 1 of constructor in demo.tripadvisorapp.security.appuser.impl.AppUserServiceImpl required a bean of type 'demo.tripadvisorapp.security.token.CustomizedUserRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'demo.tripadvisorapp.security.token.CustomizedUserRepository' in your configuration
```

Comment: Hi&Welcome! "Could not create query for public abstract int demo.tripadvisorapp.security.appuser.AppUserRepository.enableAppUser(java.lang.String); Reason: No property 'enableAppUser' found for type 'AppUser'; ..."!!

Comment: Do you want "Custom Implementations for Spring Data Repositories"?? ..please [read here (current version)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) ...what should enableUser (in repository)do?

Comment: @xerx593 Sorry, but I'm not sure I understand what you want to say :/

Comment: No, you rather want: 1. query a user (findByEmail()!?;) 2. (when found,) set enabled. 3. Store to db. ?

Comment: Something like that, I managed to create a custom repository and errors are solved, but I didnt try yet with postman because I got a new error. Check updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the stacktrace from top to bottom:

`AppUserService` depends on `AppUserRepository`.

Query method `enableAppUser` in `AppUserRepository` has a query that can't be created because `AppUser` doesn't have an `enableAppUser` property.

Now working from bottom to top:

The `AppUser` class has a property called `enabled`, **not** `enableAppUser`.

Either fixing the property on the entity or defining the mongo query with an annotation instead of the use of magic methods should solve the problem.

EDIT

As specified in the comments, the goal is to enable a user by a given email. To do this a custom query needs to be written to (1) find the user (entity) by email address and then (2) set the enabled property to true.

One quick solution is to

1. Define a query method to find an entity by email in the repository
2. Manipulate the entity in the service (set enabled to true)
3. Use the repository's normal persistence methods to save the modified entity

Comment: Yes, `AppUser` has a property called `enabled` and not `enableAppUser`, `enabled` field is boolean to check if account is verified, which I do with `enableAppUser` `enableAppUser` is method to enable user acc if he verified it via email. Btw. I'm following Amigos Code tutorial for Spring Security with email verification, he is not using Mongo so I already had some troubles on my way to make it, and this is one of them that I couldnt solve yet

Comment: I updated the answer, don't have time to write a complete solution, good luck